# When should I use static data members vs. const global variables?

Tags: c++11, global-variables, declaration, static-members, linkage

Declaring *const* global variables has proven useful to determine some functioning parameters of an API. For example, on my API, the minimum order of numerical accuracy operators have is 2; thus, I declare:

```
const int kDefaultOrderAccuracy{2};
```

as a global variable. Would it be better to make this a `static const` public data member of the classes describing these operators? When, in general, is better to choose one over the other?

Comment: can you say a few more words about *has proven useful to determine some functioning parameters*?

Comment: ... what about default parameters?

Comment: It depends on your API, but I think a common approach is as follows. If it's only used in one class then make it a static data member or member `enum`. If it's used across the entire API use macro or an enum, f.ex. `enum class OrderAccuracy { kDefault = 2, /* ... */ };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const int kDefaultOrderAccuracy{2};
```

is the declaration of a static variable: `kDefaultOrderAccuracy` has internal linkage. Putting **names with internal linkage in a header is obviously an extremely bad idea**, making it extremely easy to violate the One Definition Rule (ODR) in other code with external linkage in the same or other header, notably when the name is used in the body of an inline or template function:

Inside f.hpp:

```
template <typename T>
const T& max(const T &x, const T &y) {
  return x>y ? x : y;
}

inline int f(int x) {
  return max(kDefaultOrderAccuracy, x); // which kDefaultOrderAccuracy?
}
```

As soon as you include `f.hpp` in two TU (Translation Units), **you violate the ODR**, as the definition is not unique, as it uses a namespace static variable: which `kDefaultOrderAccuracy` object the definition designates depends on the TU in which it is compiled.

A static member of a class has external linkage:

```
struct constants {
  static const int kDefaultOrderAccuracy{2};
};

inline int f(int x) {
  return max(constants::kDefaultOrderAccuracy, x); // OK
}
```

There is only one `constants::kDefaultOrderAccuracy` in the program.

You can also use namespace level global constant objects:

```
extern const int kDefaultOrderAccuracy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Context is always important.

- To answer questions like this.
- Also for naming itself.

If you as a reader (co-coder) need to guess what an identifier means, you start looking for more context, this may be supported through an API doc, often included in decent IDEs. But if you didn't provide a really great API doc (I read this from your question), the only context you get is by looking where your declaration is placed.

Here you may be interested in the name(s) of the containing library, subdirectory, file, namespace, or class, and last not least in the type being used.

If *I* read `kDefaultOrderAccuracy`, I see a lot of context encoded (*Default*, *Order*, *Accuracy*), where *Order* could be related for sales or sorting, and the `k` encoding doesn't say anything to me. Just to make you looking on your actual problem from a different perspective. C/C++ Identifiers have a poor grammar: they are restricted to rules for compound words.

This limitation of global identifiers is the most important reason why I mostly avoid global variables, even constants, sometimes even types. If its the meaning is limited to a given context, define a thing right *within* this context. Sometimes you first have to *create this context*.

Your explanation contains some unused context:

- *numerical operators*

  - *minimum precision* (BTW: *minimum* doesn't mean *default*)

The problem of placing a definition into the right class is not very different from the problem to find the right place for a global: you have to find/create the right header file (and/or namespace).

As a side note, you may be interested to learn that also [`enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) can be used to get cheap compile-time constants, and enums can also be placed into classes (or [namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)). Also a [scoped enumeration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations) is an option you should consider before introducing global constants. As with enclosing class definitions, the `::` is a means of punctuation which separates more than `_` or an in-word `caseChange`.

#### Addendum:

If you are interested in providing a useful default behaviour of your operations that can be overridden by your users, [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) could be an option. If your API provides operators, you should study how the [input/output manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)  for the standard I/O streams work.

Comment: The `k` letter is a common prefix for constants in Hungarian notation, so it's understandable for most developers.

Comment: the `k` letter does not add information about meaning/context/grouping.

Answer (score -3):

my guess is that:
const takes up inline memory based on size of data value such as “mov ah, const value” for each use, which can be a really short command, in size overall, overall, based on input value.
whereas static values takes up a whole full data type, usually int, whatever that maybe on the current system for each static, maybe more, plus it may need a full memory access value to access the data, such as mov ah, [memory pointer], which is usually size of int on the system, for each use (with a full class it could even more complex).  yet the static is still declared const so it may behave the same as the normal const type.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11547844)

Comment: what clarification was I asking for? the only thing I am not sure of is how const static are handled.  them providing more information will not provide me with information I am unsure of.  if const static are handled the same as const the difference is meaningless (or no difference), if const static is handled in a more complex way, as previously stated, const static adds extra overhead.  sticking with const is not going to add move overhead then const static (at least I hope not), yet const static may be more natural to use.